# C# modification of read-only field via reference

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, class-design, encapsulation

I'm coming from C++ and I dearly miss "const" in C#.

I have tracked down a nasty bug in my code, consider this:

```
class MyClass {
    BitArray myFlags { get; private set; } // this should not be able to be manipulated from outside

    // ... constructor here creating the BitArray ...
}

// ...

MyClass foo = new MyClass();

BitArray bar = foo.myFlags;
bar.SetAll(false); // circumvents encapsulation eventually putting the class in inconsitent state
```

The user can without any problems, even unintendedly change the state of my object.
How do I expose members of a class safely, without giving the user the chance to manipulate the state of my object? Do I have to ".clone()" every single reference-based member (so basically everything) when providing a public (read) access to this member?

What I want to achieve is proper encapsulation. When a user creates an instance of my class, and reads a member, I want the member to be protected against writing, unless it also has a public setter.

Comment: `readonly` does not affect the instance the field points to.  C# has no language-level immutability (yet).

Comment: See also my blog, http://blog.slaks.net/2013-06-11/readonly-vs-immutable/

Comment: How about making `myFlags` private and write your own get/set methods, where you can check consistency?

Comment: @Corak sadly this doesnt change anything. Even if you make it private, and create a getter (the user of my class should be able to inspect the flags in some form) the user will still manage to obtain a reference, and then can despite all the privateness modify the state.

Comment: Although not always appropriate. I would say try not not expose any internal state, but operations only. If in your example `BitArray` is more than an implementation detail, and the user of your class should have access to all/many (non-mutating) `BitArray` methods you can either return a copy of it, or write a wrapper around it that exposes only those methods.

Answer (score 0):

C# offers ReadOnlyCollection as option for immutable collection.

Hope it helps!